# Displaying posts with users in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web

I m new to laravel i want to display all the posts on a view with the name of the user who created the post.. I m trying to do that but I m getting the error of "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object " ..
Any kind of help will be appreciated Thank you

**User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

     public function Posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Post'); 
     }
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','verifyToken','dob',
    ];
```

**Post.php**

```
class Post extends Model
{

    public function Users(){
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\User');   
    }
    protected $fillable = [

     'title','body','thumbnail','user_id',

    ];
```

**PostController.php**

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
       $posts=Post::paginate(5);
       return view('\home2',compact('posts'));


}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/home2', 'PostController@index')->name('home');
```

**Home2.blade.php**

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
<div class="text-center">
<h1 align="center">{{$post->title }}</h1>
<h4 align="center">{{$post->body}}</h4>
<p>{{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</p>
<p> {{$post->Users->name}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Eager](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) load the users:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
       $posts=Post::with('users')->paginate(5);
       return view('\home2',compact('posts'));


}
```

Then on the blade:

```
<p> {{$post->user->name}}</p>
```

Update your relationship classes
from:

```
public function Posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Post'); 
}
```

to

```
public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class); 
}
```

Import at the top `use App\Post;`
and

```
  public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);   
}
```

Import at the top `use App\User;`

Comment: @Inam when u declare relationships remove a '\' not `\App\Post` but `App\Post` if that does not work then on your index method do a `dd($posts)` and tell me what you get.

Comment: @Inam dd($posts) on the method and show me what you get

Comment: #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Post {#504 ▶}
  ]
}
I got this

Comment: @Inam dude open the collection press  ▶ and then show me that conten

Comment: #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Post {#504 ▼
      #fillable: array:4 [▼
        0 => "title"
        1 => "body"
        2 => "thumbnail"
        3 => "user_id"
      ]
      #dates: array:2 [▼
        0 => "created_at"
        1 => "updated_at"
      ]

Comment: @Inam check the updated answer define the relationships exactly as I did

Answer (score 1):

Your models should look like this.

User.php

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

Post.php

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
}
```

then your blade code should be like this,

```
<p> {{$post->user->name}}</p>
```

Comment: It is my pleasure, if my answer helped you